# UICollectionView's scrollToItem not calling targetContentOffset

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view that implements paging that is why I override the `targetContentOffset` in a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to handle it. It gets called when the collection view is scrolled through user interaction and it works. However, it does not get called when using `scrollToItem` or the scroll to visible rect. What would be the best way to scroll to the collection view programmatically that will surely go through the method `targetContentOffset`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have used bellow method for Maintain paging  and scrolling programmatically.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
     if scrollView.contentOffset.y > -topHeaderView.frame.size.height && scrollView.contentOffset.y < -20 - 50 {
            let aHeaderHeight = topHeaderView.frame.size.height
            if velocity.y <= 0  {
                targetContentOffset.memory = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -aHeaderHeight)
            } else {
                targetContentOffset.memory = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20 + 50)
            }
     }
}
```

Hope this will help you.